# how to set round-off precision in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to illustrate the stability of some numerical algorithms. I want to use Mathematica to round floating point numbers according to the usual rule, for example:

`myRound[3/80.]=0.038` if I specify the precision to be 2-digit.

Another one

```
myRound[89/47.]=1.89
```

So given a precision number, how to write the `myRound` function? Please help. Many thanks.

Comment: Surely you know that `Round` is a built-in function, with a somewhat different meaning meaning, right? Wouldn't you'd prefer to give your function a different name?

Comment: @David, right. Just forgot to distinguish my own version of `Round`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure is this is what you would like:

```
In[34]:= customRound[x_Real] := 
 Round[x, 10^Round[RealExponent[x]]*0.01]

In[35]:= customRound[3/80.]

Out[35]= 0.038

In[36]:= customRound[89/47.]
```

The function actually changes the number, as opposed to merely changing the way it is displayed.

Comment: yes, this is what I want! However, is there any simple way to change all of the functions such as Add, Substract, Times, Exp, etc. so that whenever they see real numbers they do arithmetics according to this rounding rule?

Comment: @QiangLi Yes, but this might have unintended consequences so use it at your own risk. Set `$Post = Function[Replace[#, x_Real :>customRound[x]]]`

Answer (score 5):

You should look into `NumberForm`.  For example:

```
NumberForm[89.0/47.0, 3]
```

Returns 1.89.

Acutally, it occurs to me that if you really want to illustrate round off issues, you should look into the `ComputerArithmetic` package.  It's well documented, so I'll leave it at that.

Comment: but it does not work for the first example. In my Mma, I got 0.0375 for that one. Ideally I want to use floating point representation of numbers.

Comment: @Qiang - Try, `NumberForm[3/80., {3, 3}]`.

Comment: also, this way the numbers are not operable any more. I would want every arithmetic operations to produce the round-off numbers, rather than just showing me some special form but the internal representation is still full precision. Can this be done?

Comment: @Qiang - Correct. Like most of the `*Form` functions, `NumberForm` is a wrapper that affects display but not content. `SetAccuracy` might work for you but I suspect that the introduction of arbitrary precision into your computations could be problematic.

Comment: @Qiang - See addtion on `ComputerArithmetic`.